# Firebase Rules - Allow Writing to a Certain Path in Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am depending on a Real-time database to get data for my app from this structure:

[image: Data structure]

*Each `A` has 3 `B`*

Reading is working fine under these rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

---

Now, I am in the **testing mode** & I want to achieve **two** things:

**1.** Give users the permission to write **exclusively** to the path `/../B3/` in each `A`.

**2.** The value entered by users in `/../B3/` must be a number (preferably Integer).

So, I made some research and came up with this set of rules:

```
{

  "rules": {
    "A1":{
          "B1":{
            ".read": true,
            ".write": false
           },
          "B2":{
            ".read": true,
            ".write": false
           },
        "B3":{
          ".read": true,
          ".write": true,
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() % 1 === 0.0"
         }
   },
    "A2":{
          "B1":{
            ".read": true,
            ".write": false
           },
          "B2":{
            ".read": true,
            ".write": false
           },
        "B3":{
          ".read": true,
          ".write": true,
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() % 1 === 0.0"
         }
   },
    "A3":{
          "B1":{
            ".read": true,
            ".write": false
           },
          "B2":{
            ".read": true,
            ".write": false
           },
        "B3":{
          ".read": true,
          ".write": true,
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() % 1 === 0.0"
         }
   }
}
```

---

**Problem:**

I tested these rules using playground simulator on Firebase Console and got the right results. But when I tried reading or writing on my testing device to `/../B3/`, it did not work. Instead, I got this exception in LogCat:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:229)
    at com.app.activity$3.onCancelled(activity.java:567)
```

I think I Am missing something in structuring rules. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this! Pheww!

**Solution:**

```
{

  "rules": {
".read": true, //The difference
    "A1":{
        "B3":{
          ".write": true,
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() % 1 === 0.0"
         }
   },
    "A2":{
        "B3":{
          ".write": true,
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() % 1 === 0.0"
         }
   },
    "A3":{
        "B3":{
          ".write": true,
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() % 1 === 0.0"
         }
   }
}
```

**Explanation:**

I was missing the permission to read from the root node, And according to cascading principle it is impossible to access to child nodes if you can't access to their parent (even with `".read": true` for each child). (Logical!)

**Where I Found it :** A video of 43 minutes [The key to Firebase security - Google I/O 2016](https://youtu.be/PUBnlbjZFAI) :P

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the rules need to be structured as

```
{

  "rules": {
    "A1":{
          "B1":{
            ".read": true,
            ".write": false
           },
          "B2":{
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true //changed
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() % 1 === 0.0" //added
           },
        "B3":{
          ".read": true,
          ".write": false, //changed
         }
   }
.
. //rest of the rules in the same pattern
.
```

since you want users to write **exclusively** to `/../B2` node in each `A`  subtree they should **only** be allowed access to the `/../B2` node in each `A` subtree

Also **.validate** rules aren't needed on `/../B3`, to which you don't want the user to write, as according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#validate)

> **.validate**
> Used once a .write rule has granted access, to ensure that the data being written conforms to a specific schema.

Finally, a **.validate** statement needs to exist on `/../B2` to check if the number is an integer.

As for the exception, it is quite clear that a `Permission Denied` error was given because **.write** had been set to `false` in `/../B2`.

Also, a side note, setting `".write": true` doesn't just allow your users to write to the database, it allows **anyone** to write to the database, as the [rules docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#public) point out

> During development, you can use the public rules in place of the default rules to set your files publicly readable and writable. This can be useful for prototyping, as you can get started without setting up Authentication. This level of access means anyone can read or write to your database. You should configure more secure rules before launching your app.

So, if security is an issue in the slightest, look into the rules to make sure that you have implemented measures to enforce security.

Lastly, hope this answers your questions

Comment: Sorry, this is not working either. I apologize for misleading you, I did mean B3 not B2, I will edit my question.

Comment: If that is the case, then the write to `/../B3` must have failed due to wrong data type, had the data type been numeric?

Comment: Yeah it is numeric, I tried it after your answer, but it's not working :(

Comment: @kh3e try enabling [debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) before accessing the RTDB for the first time and repeat the steps you had taken earlier and then see what the log output says

Comment: Yash thank you so much, the issue was so simple. I posted the answer :)

Comment: @kh3e That's great. Seems like such a silly thing for me to miss in hindsight, But I guess, if it's solved, it's solved :P